# iOS UI - similar to iPhoto bottom bar UI

Tags: ios, user-interface, interface

I am new to iOS app dev. I want to create UI similar to bottom tools line in iPhoto app.
Any tutorial or tips will be really helpful.
[Click this link to see UI of iPhoto app.](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/03/hands-on-iphoto-for-ios-out-does-adobe-for-mobile-image-editing/)
First image from above link shows the bottom tool container.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a WWDC session video where they explain how they designed the iPhoto for iOS app. Why not start there?

Comment: @constantine, are you referring to the controls on the left or right side of the screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a normal UIToolbar. 
Here is a tutorial for adding UISlider to your toolbar: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/06/09/iphone-adding-uislider-to-uitoolbar/

```
// Initialize  
aSlider = [[UISlider alloc] init];
UIBarButtonItem *sliderAsToolbarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  
initWithCustomView:aSlider];
// Set the width of aSlider
[sliderAsToolbarItem setWidth:250.0];

// Add the items to the toolbar
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sliderAsToolbarItem, nil]];
```

If you search for **custom UIToolbar** you are getting tons of results with tutorials.

Here you can find a custom UITabbar: http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/

Or you can just use a view with buttons in case of toolbar or tabbar and set it to bottom.

Comment: yes I am comfortable with the code snippet provided i.e. adding items to toolbar. Here, I want these controls to work like ribbon in windows.When I press any one button from left controls, entire set of tools changes on right side, just like tabs in ribbon.

Comment: @MDT- I am referring both the controls,simultaneously in action.